# HTML5 Boilerplate tabs in IE conditional statements--why?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, conditional-statements, html5boilerplate

I am yet to find a satisfactory answer to this question (actually an answer at all!).

I'm sure most of you guys have taken a look at or worked with the html5 boilerplate project. You may have seen or be familiar with the following conditionals for IE:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Now my question is, is there any particular reason for the tabs between the opening conditional/comment tag and the `html` tags? What would happen if I removed these and formatted in the following manner:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js lt-ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->
```

I just don't understand the reason for this. If I format as in the case directly above, will this trigger some kind of quirks mode in IE? Really, I just find it an odd thing to look at. I mean I can see that visually all the `html` tags line up but besides this, what am I missing here? I should mention that I traditionally come from a `C` background and so my apologies if this is an obvious noob question.

Many thanks. I appreciate any and all advice.

Comment: Absolutely no difference, it's a matter of code formatting. Actually, I prefer the second because it's easy to mantain and easier to read (for me at least).

Comment: Thanks for that @StefanoSanfilippo I appreciate that. I myself also much prefer the second formatting hence the question. It was causing some serious mental discord every time I would look at that. Thought it must have been for a reason. **I should mention that I edited my comment a bit to reflect that I can recognize the formatting but besides this, the reason for is exactly...? Thanks again.